# Android android.provider.Settings.Secure is not a hex value

Tags: java, android

Android document says that android.provider.Settings.Secure:

> A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated when the
>   user first sets up the device and should remain constant for the
>   lifetime of the user's device.

However, when I call this method:

```
String hardware_id = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

it returns a 16 digit number.  Shouldn't it return a 64 digit hex?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states that it returns a 64-**bit** hex value, not a 64 **digit** hex value. With a hex digit representing four bits (2<sup>4</sup> = 16), a 64-bit hex value is 16 hex characters.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, is it possible to get the 64 digit hex value?

Comment: @user1801879: There is no "64 digit hex value".